# When are MVar operations guaranteed to be uninterruptible?

Tags: haskell, concurrency, exception

The [documentation for `Control.Exception`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Control-Exception.html#g:14)  describes which operations can have async exceptions thrown, even within a `mask`ed block, saying: "The following operations are guaranteed not to be interruptible"

> takeMVar if the MVar is definitely full, and conversely putMVar if the
>   MVar is definitely empty

In what cases is an `MVar` "definitely" full or empty from the compiler's point of view? Is that even well-enough defined to enable reasoning about whether my code will break without handling async exceptions on every `MVar` operation?

Comment: I bet the compiler knows nothing about MVars at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler is not making that guarantee, that is why they are saying that.

Specifically if the `MVar` is full, then `takeMVar` does not block and by extension cannot be interrupted. Similarly for an empty `MVar` and `putMVar`, since it is not blocking, it cannot be interrupted.

The phrasing is used because if `MVar` is not full, say because it is sometimes full, sometimes not, then the guarantee is no longer true.