# theoretical deadlock in Control.Concurrent.Chan readChan

Tags: haskell, ghc

Browsing the source of readChan one finds the following implementation and comment, starting with version 4.6 of base:

```
-- |Read the next value from the 'Chan'.
readChan :: Chan a -> IO a
readChan (Chan readVar _) = do
  modifyMVarMasked readVar $ \read_end -> do -- Note [modifyMVarMasked]
    (ChItem val new_read_end) <- readMVar read_end
        -- Use readMVar here, not takeMVar,
        -- else dupChan doesn't work
    return (new_read_end, val)

-- Note [modifyMVarMasked]
-- This prevents a theoretical deadlock if an asynchronous exception
-- happens during the readMVar while the MVar is empty.  In that case
-- the read_end MVar will be left empty, and subsequent readers will
-- deadlock.  Using modifyMVarMasked prevents this.  The deadlock can
-- be reproduced, but only by expanding readMVar and inserting an
-- artificial yield between its takeMVar and putMVar operations.
```

Prior to base version 4.6, modifyMVar was used rather than modifyMVarMasked.

I don't understand what theoretical problem is solved for here. The last sentence states there is a problem if the thread yields between the takeMVar and putMVar that comprise readMVar. But as readMVar executes under mask_, how can an async exception prevent the put after successful take?

Any help understanding the issue here is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Let's compare the source of `modifyMVar` and `modifyMVarMasked`, since the code changed from using one to using the other:

```
modifyMVar m io =
  mask $ \restore -> do
    a      <- takeMVar m
    (a',b) <- restore (io a) `onException` putMVar m a
    putMVar m a'
    return b

modifyMVarMasked m io =
  mask_ $ do
    a      <- takeMVar m
    (a',b) <- io a `onException` putMVar m a
    putMVar m a'
    return b
```

The key here is that `modifyMVar` calls `restore` before executing its second argument, whereas `modifyMVarMasked` does not. So `readMVar` was *not* called under `mask_` in the old version of the code as you claim in your question! It was called under `restore`, instead, and therefore asynchronous exceptions could be enabled after all.

Comment: Disclaimer: I'm very much not an expert, and I've been wrong about concurrency in many languages many times before.

Comment: don't feel too badly, everyone's been wrong about concurrency many times.

Comment: @DanielWagner but `readMVar` re-masks exceptions, no? That explanation in the comment seems fishy to me

Comment: @DanielWagner Hi Daniel. Thanks for the idea, but I was actually referring to the mask_ in the implementation of readMVar. I'm still not clear as to when an  async exception could arrive that could lead to deadlock since read_end will always be "put" after a successful "take", and modifyMVar (even in non-masked form) will putMVar the head back to its original value on async exception. From Control.Exception "There's an implied mask around every exception handler in a call to one of the catch family of functions."

Answer (score 0):

Here's me working through it.

So in readMVar...

```
readMVar :: MVar a -> IO a
readMVar m =
  mask_ $ do
    a <- takeMVar m
    putMVar m a
    return a
```

...despite the `mask_` the runtime may raise an exception in a blocked `takeMVar`. Note in that function there's no need to actually *handle* that case; either the `readMVar` worked, in which case we're safe from async exceptions, or the `takeMVar` never succeeds; either way we never break the `MVar` by leaving it empty. (**Is this correct? This is what I took away from the answer to my own [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20909425/when-are-mvar-operations-guaranteed-to-be-uninterruptible).**)

`modifyMVar` and `modifyMVarMasked` are:

```
modifyMVar :: MVar a -> (a -> IO (a,b)) -> IO b
modifyMVar m io =
  mask $ \restore -> do
    a      <- takeMVar m
    (a',b) <- restore (io a) `onException` putMVar m a
    putMVar m a'
    return b

modifyMVarMasked :: MVar a -> (a -> IO (a,b)) -> IO b
modifyMVarMasked m io =
  mask_ $ do
    a      <- takeMVar m
    (a',b) <- io a `onException` putMVar m a
    putMVar m a'
    return b
```

...where the difference is in `modifyMVar` the masking state is restored (i.e. async exceptions probably become unmasked) in `io a`, which in our case is more or less `readMVar`.

**EDIT**: Although `readMVar` is `mask_`-ed as well, so now I can't see why either choice of `modifyMVarMasked` or `modifyMVar` would make a difference...

The comment seems to imply that `yield` (inserted into `readMVar`) is interruptible (I can't find this documented anywhere) and so an async exception might be raised, in which case `readVar` would be restored (in both current and pre-4.6 versions), but in a non-empty queue readers would see an empty one and block.

Comment: That is my read too. It implies something special about yield but its unclear what that could be. And if there is some theoretical  problem here wouldn't that same problem exist with every usage of readMVar? As for other readers of a non-empty queue,  shouldn't they be blocked on the outer readVar? If an async  exception is thrown to  one reader that just got a value, the `onException` in modifyMVar (masked or not) will fire and restore readVar to the previous head. So I'm still stumped about where the problem is that modivyMVarMasked solves.

Comment: @wrl yeah, after several rethinks it seems like the only difference would be the async exception raised within `restore` but before the `mask_` in readMVar is entered, but I don't see how `yield` would matter there.

Comment: I doubt there's anything special about yield, rather I think that inserting any interruptible op between the `takeMVar` and `putMVar` would allow the deadlock to be reproduced.  But without inserting an interruptible op, the deadlock won't actually be possible.

Comment: @JohnL That makes sense, any interruptible operation that got inserted there could  lead to deadlock. But how does using modifyMVarMasked solve this? As I understand the only way to mask async exceptions in an interruptible call is to use uninterruptibleMask.

Comment: @wrl I don't think `modifyMVarMasked` does solve it.  I think the committer overlooked that `readMVar` does its own `mask_` (or perhaps that was added later).  But I don't think it's a real problem, because it seems very unlikely that somebody will add an interruptible op into the middle of `readMVar`.

Answer (score 0):

You may be interested in reading the GHC trac on this commit,  which has a sample program that consistently reproduces this bug when both `Control.Concurrent.Chan` and the test program are compiled `-O0`

https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/6153

In a similar vein:

https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/5870